# CAPL on sysvar_change procedure with sysvar of custom struct data type

Tags: capl

according to the manual,

> The procedure on sysVar is called only when the value of the variable
>   changes. It can also be written as on sysVar_change. If you want to be
>   notified of value updates to the variable which don’t change the
>   value, you should use on sysVar_update instead.

In my example scenario, I have a system variable `s::sysv` of custom Struct Data Type `X`, where `X` has two fields: `A` and `B`.

In my CAPL script I put the following:

```
on sysvar_change s::sysv.A
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Expected output is to do stuff only when `s::sysv.A` changes. However, since `s::sysv.B` is often updated when my simulation is running, then the procedure `on sysvar_change s::sysv.A` is called a lot more times than I expect, even if `A` doesn't change its value.

I don't understand why, and I'm putting a lot of workaround in place to avoid this, can anybody help?

---

**Edit:**

according to one reply, the event handler is not the struct element, but still the variable. However, the keyword `this` is now pointing to the struct element and not to the variable.

This bit of the manual is also relevant:

> You can also react in the same way to value changes of specific
>   elements of a system variable of type struct or generic array. For
>   this, add the element to the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this functionality in the latest CANoe and it works as expected. The following is my code.

```
on key 'a'
{
  @sysvar::Var_Struct1.StructMem1++;
}
on key 'b'
{
  @sysvar::Var_Struct1.StructMem2++;
}

on sysvar_change Var_Struct1.StructMem1
{
  write("StructMem1 value changed");
}
on sysvar_change Var_Struct1.StructMem2
{
  write("StructMem2 value changed");
}
```

Whenever I press the key 'a' or 'b', the corresponding event is triggered.

Comment: I'm using v10, which version did you test on?

Comment: I have tested this on v10 SP7 (64bit)

Comment: aah, okok. CANoe v13 is out, that was confusing for me. So the output of your CAPL is just the single variable change, while on my system it doesn't. I'll review the MVCE and be back to you, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `s::sysv`. The event handler is called whenever the value of the variable changes. No matter whether `A` or `B` changes.

There is no way to restrict it only to certain changes of the value.

This is similar to the fact that you can also not be notified when, e.g. only the 3rd bit of an integer changes.

To me, it seems best to reconsider your setup and ask yourself, whether using the struct is the right approach, or whether it might be better to use two separate system variables `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, when I read this bit in the help, it doesn't imply that the struct child is becoming the new event handler, even though now the `this` keyword is referring to the child `s::sysv.A`, and not to the parent `s::sysv`? `You can also react in the same way to value changes of specific elements of a system variable of type struct or generic array. For this, add the element to the name of the variable.`

Comment: You are right, this is written in the documentation. It might be worth to contact the Vector support. I cannot remember that these selective events have ever worked.